# Create dynamic arrays using for loop with jquery/javascript can not access outside or cant access global

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have need to create arrays dynamically using `JavaScript/JQuery`.
What I did is as follows:

```
var count = 5;
for(var j=0;j<count;j++){
        var arrayname = "array"+j;
        var arrayname  = [];    
    }
```

After creation I am expecting `arrays array0[],array1[],array2[],array3[],array4[]`

So I printed as

```
alert(array0);
```

But I am getting error as follows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: array0 is not defined
```

It occurred because `array0[]` is not global its bound is only inside that for loop. How can I create dynamic array so that all the arrays can be accessed from outside also?

Comment: Why not use a single variable? An array in JavaScript can hold additional arrays within it, creating a structure similar to a multi-dimensional array – `var array = []; for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) array.push([]);`. With that, `array0[1]` would instead be `array[0][1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)** to define variable dynamically

```js
var count = 5;
for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
  eval('var array' + j + '=[]');
}

console.log(array0);
```

Comment: I need 5 dynamic arrays or wrt to the counter why it needs JSON? You mean all my 5 `array0...array4` act as arrays?So I can make `push `operations in these arrays?

Comment: @Santhucool :  just for converting to string, for alerting

Comment: thanks buddy this is what I am looking for!!